# How to convert this query from MySQL to PostgreSQL:

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have been struck by this conversion

**MYSQL**

```
IF((select SUM(MT2.TOTAL) from U_001_01_MMTRANS MT2 where MT2.CMPGLINEREF!=0 AND MT2.MAINLINEREF 
IN (select MT3.LOGICALREF from U_001_01_MMTRANS MT3 where MT3.ITEMREF=ITM.LOGICALREF AND MT3.LINETYPE=0 AND MT3.INVOICEREF=INV.LOGICALREF)) IS NULL, 0.00, 
(select SUM(MT2.TOTAL) from U_001_01_MMTRANS MT2 where MT2.CMPGLINEREF!=0 AND MT2.MAINLINEREF 
IN (select MT3.LOGICALREF from U_001_01_MMTRANS MT3 where MT3.ITEMREF=ITM.LOGICALREF AND MT3.LINETYPE=0 AND MT3.INVOICEREF=INV.LOGICALREF))) AS TRAONV
```

I have tried to covert like this, but it was not accepted:

**PostgreSQL**

```
CASE when 
(select SUM(MT4.TOTAL) from U_002_01_MMTRANS MT4
where MT4.CMPGLINEREF!=0 AND MT4.MAINLINEREF 
IN (select MT5.LOGICALREF from U_002_01_MMTRANS MT5 where MT5.ITEMREF=ITM.LOGICALREF 
AND MT5.LINETYPE=0 AND MT5.INVOICEREF=INV.LOGICALREF)) IS NULL then 0.00
else 
(select SUM(MT4.TOTAL) from U_002_01_MMTRANS MT4 where MT4.CMPGLINEREF !=0 AND MT4.MAINLINEREF
IN (select MT5.LOGICALREF from U_002_01_MMTRANS MT5 where MT5.ITEMREF=ITM.LOGICALREF AND MT5.LINETYPE=0 
AND MT5.INVOICEREF=INV.LOGICALREF)) end as TRAONV
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The original query is repeating a single table table four times. Are you sure this is needed? DRY, Don’t Repeat Yourself, is a good thing in (database) programming. I would first get my requirements right and then write a new query. I would definitely not try to repeat the original query

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL query is ridiculously inefficient since you repeat the same query twice to get a single result.

In PostgreSQL you can use the `coalesce()` function which will return the first non-NULL element in a list, like so:

```
select coalesce(SUM(TOTAL), 0.00) as TRAONV
from U_001_01_MMTRANS
where CMPGLINEREF <> 0 
  and MAINLINEREF IN (
    select MT3.LOGICALREF
    from U_001_01_MMTRANS MT3
    join ITM on MT3.ITEMREF = ITM.LOGICALREF    -- check these joins
    join INV on MT3.INVOICEREF = INV.LOGICALREF -- possibly other conditions
    where MT3.LINETYPE = 0                      -- or WHERE clauses necessary
    )
```

Since your query was not complete, this is no more than a best effort.

I hope this also clearly demonstrates the value of proper formatting of your query